# Adding Log in/out and register links to a Specific WordPress Menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, multisite

I want to give my users the ability to log in/out and register in my primary menu. I added the snippet below in my functions.php to show log in/out links to my users appropriately on the menu location: primary. I want to add register link similar to login/log out that will be hidden for logged in users. Any insights?

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Log Out</a></li>';
    }
    elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Log In</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should note is that Wordpress `login` and `register` are hosted inside the `wp-login.php` file.
Moreso, there is a variable `$registration_url` which is only called out if **you enable user registration** from your settings dashboard. So, you can do something like this:

```
// Add your filter
function add_registration_link($items, $args){
if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
    $items .= '';
}
elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
    $items .= $registration_url;
}
return $items;
}
```

Remember you have to **enable user registration** before this can work.